# How to select (highlight) text in Skype chat without using a mouse?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

Recently I started learning to use keyboard shortcuts almost for everything I'm doing on the laptop, but soon enough after I started, I bumped into the problem of being unable to highlight (select) simple text in Skype chats.

I did some research and I couldn't find any solution to my problem. Have I missed an already answered question that is the same like mine or if not what solution can you suggest in order to achieve the results I want without touching mouse or touchpad or any cursor moving device?

Comment: I love keyboard shortcuts! However, the only way I have figured out to do this (for any text) is to highlight one or two characters using your mouse, and then using shift+arrow keys to do the rest of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly mark text in old chat window. But you can use next workaround to accomplish this:

1. Using tab key go to the text block you want to mark
2. Ctrl+c to copy it
3. Using tab go to the window where you enter text
4. Ctrl+v
5. using arrow keys navigate to the begin or to the end of text you
   want to mark
6. Press and hold shift
7. Use arrow keys to mark the text
8. Release shift
9. Ctrl+c
10. Ctrl+a
11. Backspace or del (to delete the text from the window)